# Is there any relationship between flutter state management and flutter architecture patterns(MVVM, MVC...)

Tags: flutter, model-view-controller, mvvm, flutter-provider, state-management

I know there are some flutter architecture pattern like MVC, MVVM. Also there are some flutter state management approaches like setState, Provider, Getx, Mobx, BloC/rx and inheritedWidget etc.

As I understood state management approaches are used to manage the state of the app and as I understood flutter architecture patterns are used as architecture of the flutter app(I m bit doubt about my flutter architecture patterns definition.)

So I just need to know is there any relationship between flutter state management approaches and flutter architecture patterns. or do we need to use flutter architectural pattern to organize our state management code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No. They are different.
You can use any architecture with any state management solution.
For example most of the state objects resides inside the controllers of MVC (where controller holds logic). But in DDD, it's on the presentation layer.

In summary, state management solutions used to provide the states to the screen, where patterns/architecture used to organize the whole codebase.

Comment: 1. DDD is not related to architecture at all. It is a technique to model the domain of an application or business. I think what you mean is "hexagonal architecture" or "Clean Architecture" right?

2. You got the MVC wrong. In MVC the controllers are simply connectors between a View and Models. The whole business logic resides inside the models. If the logic resides inside the "Controllers" these controllers are called View Models ( -> MVVM )

3. There is a difference between app architecture ( like Layers/ Clean Code ... ) and architectural patterns to organize the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes and No.

The term "State management" comes from web development libraries like Redux or Vuex, where you implement a store that holds the complete state of an app. These libraries build on the Flux pattern and in my eyes this is the key difference between Architecture and State management: To manage a state for the whole app rather than for parts of your app.

You are also able to implement such stores with Bloc or Riverpod e.g. to hold a user's session or data that is needed in all pages. This can be done by wrapping the whole app into a Provider ( in other words create a VM for your top level widget ). In this case one cannot say that e.g. Bloc is MVVM because you created kind of VM for the whole app.

But on the other hand ( and this is also recommended by the creators of Blocs) you are able to implement MVVM with Blocs/Cubits by restricting them to one View ( like a page or a widget ).

Long story short:

- **State Management** -> Overall state for the app
- **Architecture**  -> Classic patterns ( MVC, MVVM ... ) implemented for parts of the app as recommended in the design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

No. Sadly.

I have been programming for years, but still relatively new to Flutter, hence I am not an authority but have a fresh sight.

What I can see, is that there are two real, native things in Flutter: View and State. Almost all that is not a View is the State.

About 90% of all app's code belongs to view, 9.9% to state and 0.1% to code that interacts with plugins.

All attempts to apply existing patterns to Flutter look far-fetched.

MVC for example. `Controller` traditionally contains code, that interacts with the user. In imperative-style programming, it can be a lot of code. But in Flutter it is usually one-liners that update the state through
providers. Some authors put providers' files into the `Controller` category, but they are not exactly controllers in the traditional sense. After all, architecture is about structuring the code. And if there is not enough code to put in the `Controller` category, there is no need in the **controller** folder.

So, we remain with MV. But if we read a couple of articles about Flutter MVC we will see that authors refer to value objects as a `Model`, which is correct, but with this approach, we also have very little code to put in `Model` category. (We used that `Model` contains all code that interacts with the backend but in Flutter this code moved to providers.)

Again, what we actually have in the Flutter app are:

1. Widgets that are the `View`
2. Value objects and providers that belong to the `State`.

So, why not use State-View (or  View-State) architecture? With folder structure like below:

```
lib/src/
         main.dart
         view/
            feature1/
                    feature1.dart
                    widgets/ 
            
         state/  
             feature1/
                     feature1_vo.dart
                     feature1_provider.dart
```

I think it will suit well at least small to medium-sized apps.

**Update 2024**.
I recently started to use GetX.

GetX calls its state managers - *controllers*.

Therefore, we have an obvious architectural choice - MVC.

Hence:

```
 lib /
     controller /
                user_controller.dart
     model /
           user.dart
           user_service.dart
     view /
          user_screen.dart
```